# Implementing queue using Link in Java

Tags: java, queue

I am trying to implement queue in Java using this Link class I created.
However, I am confused as to how different it is from LinkedList provided in Java.
How could I add a new value to the end of the Link instance (in this case, I would like to add the new value to the end of first)?

```
    private static class Link<L> {
       L val;
       Link next;
       Link(L val) {
          this.val = val;
          this.next = null;
       }
    }
    private Link<T> first = null;
    private Link<T> last = null;
    
    public void put(T val) {
       Link<T> oldLast = last;
       last = new Link<T>(val);
       if (first == null) {
          first = last;
       } else {
         oldLast.next = last;
         first = oldLast;
       }
   }
```

I could only find ways to implement queue using linkedlist in google, but not with my own structure/class.

This is the take() method:

```
public T take() {
    T val = null;
    if (first != null) {
      val = first.val;
      first = first.next;
    }

    return val;
  }
```

For instance, if I try to run the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    UnsafeMessageQueue<Integer> queue = new UnsafeMessageQueue<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      queue.put(i);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      System.out.println(queue.take());
    }
  }
```

then the output printed in the terminal is 8 9.

Answer (score 0):

"First" pointer should not be updated when inserting a new item to the queue, first will always stay first in a queue unless it was pulled out. You only need to update the "last" pointer when inserting a new item.

```
public void put(T val) {
    Lint<T> item = new Link<T>(val);
    if(first == null) {
        first = item;
        last = first;
    } else {
        last.next = item;
        last = last.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, i understand it now! Thank you so much:))

Comment: @kim if the solution helped you solve your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer.